# Which are the easiest steps to enable log4j in a JAVA EE 7 (WAR) deployed on WildFly 10?

Tags: maven, log4j, war, java-ee-7, wildfly-10

Everytime I don't use a template or have to upgrade old projects I get in troubles finding which is the easiest way to configure log4j for a WAR (EE 7) that will be deployed on WildFly 10...

I'm using maven

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything. Are you seeing errors or unexpected behavior? Do you have a log4j configuration file or are you just using log4j loggers?

Comment: I really don't know.. I have a project that a colleage made for WebLogic but he needs to define log4j.xml en WEB-INF and put MAVEN dependencies as JAR, even specify the PATH of the file Appender. But In WildFly thought wasn't so complex... I uses to use the default logger but for example I don't have the option logger.debug... just log.info, log.several and others that are not so nice as Log4j.

My question is to get the right and minimu setup... 

Sometimes I feel I just copied those parts from other projects but really I don't know exactly what is the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggesting leaving the `log4j.xml` out of the deployment and configuring logging through the [logging subsystem](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Logging+Configuration.). This would allow you to make changes to the configuration at runtime without requiring a redeploy of the application or reload of the server.

For example to add a new logger with the `DEBUG` level in CLI:

```
/subsystem=logging/logger=org.jboss.as:add(level=DEBUG)
```

If you now need want to change it to `TRACE` logging:

```
/subsystem=logging/logger=org.jboss.as:write-attribute(name=level, value=TRACE)
```

You can also configure all this through the web console or the [HTTP management API](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/The+HTTP+management+API) as well.